# Trouble attaching Chrome browser for debugger with React Native in WebStorm

Tags: react-native, webstorm

Using WebStorm 2018 and trying to setup a debug config for an existing React Native project.

I've set it up to start the React Native bundler and unchecked the build and launch application option.

It opens up the Chrome browser but it's a blank page and WebStorm shows an error.

It also shows a status of

> Waiting for connection to localhost:55391... Please ensure the browser was started successfully with remote debugging port opened

Browser is open but it's set to a blank page.

Comment: please try closing all Chrome instances before starting the debug session - does the issue persist?

Comment: restarting webstorm seemed to  have solved it.